# use IN instead OR on mysql affect performance

Tags: mysql

affect performace if I replace:

```
SELECT * product WHERE product.id = 1 OR product.id = 2
```

for

```
SELECT * product WHERE product.id IN (1,2)
```

there is some similar for AND?

Comment: `SELECT * product WHERE product.id(1,2)` doesn't look like correct syntax.

Comment: sorry, I edited the query

Answer (score 0):

Well, how can a product could have its `id` set to both 1 and 2? I can't see a situation where a field can be two value at once, except maybe if MySQL became a Quantum SGBD or you are trying to get a string with two substring, let's say you want all string with Foo and Bar. In that case, the `LIKE` statement with the `%` token will be probably of great use.

Comment: are products different, I want if exist, the product with id 1 or the product with id 2.